# What does ViewsLifetime mean?

Tags: rest

I want to show hit number for a page. I found Viewslifetime. I am sorting this Descending. So what does ViewsLifeTime means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ViewsLifeTime is a search managed property which stores the life time view count of a page, list item, web etc.

So, you are correct in using this property to show the view count of a page.

By sorting it in desc order, you will show the most viewed page in a site, web etc based on your search configuration for the webpart

Comment: Could you please let me know if it based on Unique Visitor Views Count or On Request Page Views Count. Just curious to know

Comment: Its based on how many times the page has been requested and viewed by users.

Comment: Thanks Gautam.got the answer with real time use in tenant. as my dev tenant is just having 25 users but some of the pages is having views more than 350 so it must be how many times page request by users not unique user visit.